# container.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, encoding, appendchild

```
var refreshBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("refresh-button");
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

const maxpalate = 32;

function RefreshFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < maxpalate; i++) {
    let randomhex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffffff).toString(16);
    randomhex = `#${randomhex.padStart(6, "0")}`;
    const color = document.createElement("li");
    color.classList.add = "color";
    color.innerHTML = `<div class="rect-box" style="background: ${randomhex}"></div>
                          <span class="hex-value">${randomhex}</span>`;
    container.appendChild(color);
  }
}
```

I am not getting the solution,please tell me the Solution of this

Comment: there is a typo `appandChild` should be `appendChild`

Comment: appendChild() also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not appandChild it is appendChild.

Second "getElementsByClassName" returns an array but the "container" is a single element so you need to use a single element instead.

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

const maxpalate = 2;

function RefreshFunction() {
  debugger
  for (let i = 0; i < maxpalate; i++) {
    let randomhex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffffff).toString(16);
    randomhex = `#${randomhex.padStart(6, "0")}`;
    const color = document.createElement("li");
    color.classList.add = "color";
    color.innerHTML = `<div class="rect-box" style="background: ${randomhex}"></div>
                          <span class="hex-value">${randomhex}</span>`;
    container[0].appendChild(color);
  }
}

RefreshFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements. You need to use `container[0]` instead of `container`.
2. Call `appendChild` method instead of `appandChild`.